# jquery dialog - no default button

Tags: jquery, modal-dialog

How can I make the first button non-default?

Here is my dialog:

```
$('<div>' + x + '</div>').dialog({
    resizable: false,
    modal:true,
    minWidth:600,
    buttons: {
        //this is marked automatically as default:  
        "Igen, tovább a kosárhoz": function() {
            navigate("/fotokidolgozas/kosar.php");
        },
        "Nem, vissza a kezdőlapra": function() {
            navigate("/fotokidolgozas/index.php");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is actually a bug / feature in JQuery UI. [Bug ticket](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4731)

```
$('.ui-dialog :button').blur();
```

It has been addressed and will be configurable in the 1.9 release.

Comment: why do you say it is a bug? I dont think that it would be a problem to set the first button as default but in this case I dont need it.

Comment: Updated answer to be more diplomatic :)